# Selenium Webdriver Java: Checking if a piece of script is present

Tags: java, selenium, google-analytics, webdriver

I have the following piece of HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>bladibla</script>
<script>bladibla</script>

<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-Bla', 'auto');

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

</head> 

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to test if "go('send', 'pageview');" is present in that particular piece of code.

I've tried the following, but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
String header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//head[@'script'")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(header.contains("go('send', 'pageview');"));
```

Does anybody know how I can get Selenium Webdriver to check for the presence of "go('send', 'pageview');" in a Script Tag in the Head of a webpage? GetText doesn't seem to be working as it's a script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken directly from the selenium webdriver documentation. I suggest you fiddle around more before asking :)

"By Tag Name
The DOM Tag Name of the element.

Example of how to find an element that looks like this

```
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
```

written in Java:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));"
```

Changing what is here you can use sth like this:

```
String header = driver.findElement(By.tagName("script")).getText();
```

and search for contains inside that header.

Hope it is helpful
PS: the link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-tag-name

Comment: I did that, the problem is, because it's a script tag, you cannot use  'getText', it will always return a Assertion error :/ It doesn't recognize it as text, and so, you cannot 'get' it...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has the same security restrictions as a browser, and you can't view JavaScript source through the DOM API.

You can see if the page view was sent by using a [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback), like:

```
window.gaHitSent = false;
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'hitCallback': function() {
    window.gaHitSent = true;
  }
});
```

You can then check the variable with Selenium.  I'm not a Java developer, so I'm following http://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Boolean sent = js.executeScript("return typeof(gaHitSent) !== 'undefined' && gaHitSent");
```